# Using object from one fragment to another fragment, android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have two fragments in same activity class.

On first fragment I made a public object which have two lists inside it.

and populate using gson library from a json string.

then I showed first list on listview in first fragment.

Now I want to show second list on another fragment.

how can I get the same object in second fragment, so that I can use its second list.

Second fragment will open after clicking on a button which is in first fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably could create whatever objects you need and are common for your fragments in your activity and access them from fragment by `((YourActivity)getActivity()).yourObject`

Comment: This something I also found on google search, and it seems that it can help my problem. But can you please give some more details or reference of tutorial like thing?

Comment: Mean while i'm trying what i have understand from your code

Comment: when i click on button to open second fragment oncreateview doesnt run, how to assign this variable now ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that is not possible way you are trying to do.

Because it violates the OOPS principle  that one child can not have multiple parent.

So how to do this.

1) Create a common fragment with listview.

2) From activity load data as you are loading.

3) And pass data to fragment and that you want show in first and second and so on...

4) No need of two listview

5) Just change the data for listvew